# Is it safe to exclude "base-files" from update?

Tags: apt

I am using Linux **Lubuntu** 20.04.3 LTS, 64 bit and alas the latest system update didn´t go well.
It consisted of the two packages

```
base-files/focal-updates 11ubuntu5.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 11ubuntu5.4]
```

and

```
snapd/focal-updates,focal-security 2.54.3+20.04.1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.54.2+20.04ubuntu2]
```

With the help of **timeshift**  I set my system back to the state it had been a week before. So everything´s fine now.
But I´d have to perform system updates in the future anyway.

So my question is:

As I suspect **base-files** to have messed up my system, can I **safely** exclude this package from updates with

```
sudo apt-mark hold base-files
```

and after that

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

or could this be in any way disadvantageous?

Many thanks in advance.

Many greetings

Rosika

Comment: Secession from updates means you'll not receive bug fixes or new features. You can see what won't be updated: `dpkg -L base-files`. TL;DR: Not "safe". Bad Idea.

Comment: Hi @waltinator: Thanks a lot for your reply. I see. Well, the `base-files`-version I have at the present (11ubuntu5.4 ) has never triggered any problems - up to the present. The new one (version 11ubuntu5.5) seems to give me some trouble like not mounting USB-attached devices or even a third HDD-partition by default any more... On the other hand there´s still the `snapd`-package waiting for me to update. Either of the two has to be responsible. Thanks so much for providing the command `dpkg -L base-files`. It´s highly appreciated. Many greetings.